# Changing button text and behavior using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a JS method that changes depending on the state of the button, defined by the `indexOf("..some text..")`

```
$('#add1').click(function(){
    if($(this).text().indexOf("Add Me!")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '{{ URL('schedulizer/add') }}',
            data: {
                "class": ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
                _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data){
            ... do stuff ...
        });
        $(this).removeClass('btn-material-yellow-600');
        $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
        $(this).text('Remove Me!');
        return false;
    } else if($(this).text().indexOf("Remove Me!")){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '{{ URL('schedulizer/remove') }}',
            data: {
                "class": ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
                _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data){
            ... do stuff ...
        });
        $(this).removeClass('btn-danger');
        $(this).addClass('btn-material-yellow-600');
        $(this).text('Add Me!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

What works:

When I click the initial "Add Me!", it would change to "Remove Me!". However, when the state of the button is in "Remove Me!", it seems the conditional is not satisfied, and the state stays in "Remove Me" no matter how many times I press the button.

Apologies for the messy and redundant code.. I'm very very new to JS, so everything is a muck fest.

Comment: Try to remove/comment out 'done' callbacks and check if somethnig will change, or even remove ajax functions for now

Comment: What does your button look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indexOf return the position of the string it finds, and the position of your string is confusing the conditional if/else and it is always landing on the else if condition. Use `==` operator as follows :

```js
$('#add1').click(function(){
  

    if($(this).text().trim() == "Add Me!") {
        
        $(this).text('Remove Me!');
        return false;
      
    } else if($(this).text().trim() == "Remove Me!"){
       
        $(this).text('Add Me!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add1">Add Me!</button>
```

Comment: `==` and `indexOf()` won't match if there is any other text

Comment: The reason I used `indexOf` is because for some reason, the text returned from `$(this).text()` contains numerous white space before/after the `Add Me!`, so I decided to use `indexOf` instead.

Comment: use `trim($(this).text()) == 'Add Me!'` this shall remove white space  before/after the `Add Me!`

Comment: Why == instead of the stronger ===?

Comment: Well here you are safe as of type matching since javascript is string based and the button text is a string

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf()` needs a comparison when used in conditional since `0` is valid index but will be falsy in the conditional.

Use `greater than -1` for truthy test since it will be `-1` if index doesn't exist

```
if($(this).text().indexOf("Add Me!") >-1)..
```

Comment: While this works, you should use the == operator since that is what it's designed for (comparing two values).  Searching a string for a substring should only be used when the string could potentially be larger than the substring.  Using the correct code will help you if you ever revisit this code in the future so you don't spend any time trying to figure out why you were searching "Add me" for a substring value of "Add me"

Comment: The reason I used indexOf is because for some reason, the text returned from $(this).text() contains numerous white space before/after the Add Me!, so I decided to use indexOf instead.

Comment: Did you read his code?  He changes the text of the button to "Add Me" or "Remove Me".

Comment: @theGreenCabbage can use trim() or $.trim() to remove whitespace on ends

Comment: @Stan no...actually i didn't see that. regardless this answer stands as it helps OP understand where it went wrong

Comment: @charlietfl - It is always helpful to read the code in a question before you answer it (or accuse others of making assumptions).  :)

Comment: @Stan but there are unknowns...and there was a whitespace problem elsewhere not shown

Comment: @charlietfl There may be unknowns, but you wouldn't know about them because you didn't read the question.  I am not looking for an argument, but I'm surprised to see someone with your reputation answering questions without actually reading them...Do you disagree that using the == operator to compare values is a mistake when trying to determine if the text of a button is "Add Me"?!?!?!?!?

Comment: @Stan I answered what was relevant...now you are trying to argue...and the assumptions also would have been problematic....relax.

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, I will agree with you that it is best to answer questions without reading them and that, when trying to compare two strings, you should search one string to see if it contains the other string, instead of using the == operator.  You win.

Comment: But I'll add one more thing - if, in fact, he was ending up with extra characters in the text, he has another problem that should be addressed separately.

Comment: @Stan the question wasn't about methods to use it was why the code was failing. Optimizing a one click event that checks one string is fine...but does it educate OP why the code wasn't working in the first place? The insertion of text vs existing text was indeed an unknown. I'm not saying using indexOf is better... I answered the problem at hand

Comment: @charlietfl Your code would have worked, if that's what you're asking.  But there are better answers, which is why I left a comment under yours so that future visitors understand why your answer wasn't optimal.  Again, your code would accomplish the desired result.  But, again, you didn't address other problems in his code.  I think the OP would be better off fixing his code AND understanding when to use the == operator.  Furthermore, I think you would be better off understanding that you should read questions before answering them.  Unless you're just trying to get quick and easy points...

Comment: @charlietfl You're incorrigible.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<button id="add1">Add Me!</button>
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
$add1Btn = $('#add1');

$add1Btn.click(function() {
    var btnText = $add1Btn.html();
    console.log(btnText);

    if (btnText === 'Add Me!') {
            $add1Btn.html('Remove Me!');
    } else if (btnText === 'Remove Me!') {
            $add1Btn.html('Add Me!');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zymcm6jv/

Your AJAX calls may be causing an issue if things don't seem to be working properly. Also, I think you would want to be putting the change of text in the success call back for the AJAX call, that way the text will change once the response has been received.